# How to obtain access token in Cloud Functions for Firebase when user signs up?

Tags: swift, firebase, github, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

When a client signs in with Github, I would like to trigger a Cloud Function that retrieves the user's profile data from Github and stores it in `/users/{uid}/profile` in the Realtime database.

I can trigger my cloud function when a new user signs up using:

```
exports.fetchProfile = functions.auth.user().onCreate(event => {
  // user = event.data
  // uid = user.uid
  // access_token = ???

  // todo: request user profile from Github using access_token
  // todo: save profile in /users/{uid}/profile
});
```

But, how do I obtain the user's `access_token` needed for making the Github profile request? Thanks.

**What I have tried:**

1. On the client, use FirebaseAuth to get the Github `access_token`.
2. Create a Firebase `credential` using the `access_token` from (1).
3. Sign in with the `credential` from (2), I get a `FIRUser` in success callback, from which I can obtain `uid`.
4. I write `{uid: access_token}` to a queue in the Realtime database, this in turn triggers my cloud function that does the profile retrieval.

All these just to get the user's `access_token`, can I do better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it with the user creation trigger.
You have multiple options:

1. after sign up, get the access token from the client and saved it in the real-time database under a location accessible by the specified user. You can then set a cloud functions database trigger for that location. When that is triggered, you get the access token and make your API call to GitHub and get the data and do whatever you want with it.
2. Run everything on the client side. Since you have the access token after sign up in the client (browser), make the API call to GitHub and then save the profile data in a database location accessible by the user only. You can add a cloud function to trigger on changes to that location if you need to run additional admin operations.

By the way, Firebase Auth (4.0.0) now returns additional user data. Check: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth#.UserCredential
You can get the additional data by calling result.additionalUserInfo.profile, or the GitHub username:  result.additionalUserInfo.username.

Comment: Thanks @bojeil, I am already using option 1, and I'll probably stick with that because option 2 leads to code duplication on different clients (Web, iOS, and Android). It would have been nice though if I could get the access_token from the user creation trigger.

Comment: It would be awesome if `additionalUserInfo` was accessible from `onCreate` event. After all, if we are logging in via Facebook with extra permissions, we surely want to store gathered data somewhere. What is the point of making it accessible via the client, but not via backend?

Comment: You can do it indirectly - https://stackoverflow.com/a/67188460/271450