# How to get ID Token in Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, jwt

I need to access **user.getIdToken()** from firebase cloud functions.  I am creating a user like so:

```js
exports.addUser = functions.auth
  .user()
  .onCreate((user: admin.auth.UserRecord) =>
    admin.auth()
      .setCustomUserClaims(user.uid, {
        "custom_claims": {
          "USER": user.email,
          "ROLE": 'SUBSCRIBER'
        }
      })
      .then(async () => {
      ...
      // get token
      const token = user.getIdToken();

      // run fetch
      fetch(URL, OPTIONS_WITH_TOKEN);
```

Obviously `user.getIdToken()` does not work here, as that is a client method.

`createCustomToken` does not seem to be the same thing, as it does not contain all the same information (hence it is a custom token), and it adds a claims object instead of inserting the object directly.

How can I get a regular token for a header to run a fetch?

Thanks,

J

Comment: Can you add some links to documentation (what is `getIdToken()` or `createCustomToken` ?) What kind of fetch do you want to perform?

Comment: I figured it out - https://stackoverflow.com/a/67188460/271450